# Does the anomalous voting algorithm detect downvotes on trolls?

Tags: support, serial-voting

If I heavily downvote a troll will the vote fraud algorithm rollback my votes or is this considered?

Perhaps it should take into account if other users also downvoted him to tartarus

Comment: I didn't mean I went to old post and vote them down, but the troll may have posted a lot of posts on the same day

Comment: do you mean that you just happen to come across like 6 answers/questions in a row by that user and you downvote all of them? This happens to me sometimes and I wonder about this

Comment: Yes, they are posts deserving of downvotes that happen to be from the same user (by chance of course)

Comment: @Earlz many of us, when we find a user abusing the system, will go through and spot check their history. Often times it turns out they have been "getting away with it", and many older posts deserve downvotes and/or flags. The downside is that if you push the limit on this, the anti-retaliation script will undo your handiwork.

Comment: @Jon I do this also, but I restrain myself from downvoting because of the anti-serial-downvote thing. But I don't restrain from using spam flags

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I would do is limit my anti-troll voting pattern to just a couple of really nasty posts, and let all the really old stuff stay as is. If the user is really all that bad the total effect of a bunch of us doing the same will get the point across. And you can still flag, too.

Edit:

If a troll is particularly active, flagging for moderator attention is probably more effective than simple downvoting.

Comment: I don't vote on old stuff, but there are really active trolls these days

Comment: No need to add my response, it would be the same as Jon B's..