# Downvoting repetitive questions by the same person

Tags: discussion, serial-voting

Suppose a person asks a question that is not valid, and repeats it many times with some changes. If I always downvote that question, is that serial downvoting or not? I think it should not be considered serial downvoting.

Comment: Note that question is rate limited; it may well be that you *cannot* trigger the serial downvoting algorithm because noone is allowed to ask enough questions fast enough.

Comment: well, if you visit his profile and proceed to downvote each of his questions, than that probabably would be

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does the anomalous voting algorithm detect downvotes on trolls?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48895/does-the-anomalous-voting-algorithm-detect-downvotes-on-trolls)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you deliver many downvotes to many different questions in a short time period, the serial downvoting detection algorithm is likely to fire and unwind them. If you think that someone is posting many duplicate copies of a question, vote to close as duplicate, or flag for a moderator, or both.

Comment: If they're constantly changing (and improving) the question each time that may not be appropriate.  It would depend on the context; they might want to just edit their question, but if they already have answers then editing might invalidate them (and that would be discouraged).

Comment: Then they should be editing the one question.

Comment: As I said in my comment, if there have been answers to it and the edit is significant enough that it would invalidate the answer(s) then no, they shouldn't be editing the question.  Follow up questions, at least in certain circumstances, do belong in separate questions, not as edits to the OP.  It does depend on context though, and there is no concrete example provided.

Answer (score 2):

It depends from when the questions are asked, and when you down-vote them. If the user keeps asking the same question (with some variants) every two days, and you down-vote them when they are asked, it is probably not considered serial down-voting; if you down-vote 10 questions in 10 seconds, that is caught by the serial down-voting script.
There aren't details about how the serial down-voting script works (for obvious reasons), but consider the script is supposed to catch a specific voting pattern, where the user votes posts from the same user without having the time to read them.